# Fuzzy_like_this query in elastic search not showing string with apostrophe

Tags: elasticsearch, apostrophe, fuzzy-search

I have an uissue in my fuzzy_like_this query
If my string contains any Apostrophe then its not searching those values contains in db.

sample

citrus's => search string
but results not selecting the apostrophe values instead getting like
citrus, so and so..
pls do help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

elastic search accepts the Apostrophe.so please double check your query

Answer (score 1):

6 unicode characters can represent an 'apostrophe' in documents. It can be either u0027, u2018, u2019, u201B, u0091 or u0092

Out of the six, Elasticsearch recognises three unicode characters as 'apostrophe' : u0027, u2018 and u2019.

So, I think your apostrophe must be last 3 unicode character, which Elasticsearch assumes as word boundaries. So, citrus's will be tokenize as citrus only.

Adding a char_filter in your analyzer might help you. All the six characters will be replaced by proper 'apostrophe' u0027

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/index_name(your_index) -d '
{
"settings": {
"analysis": {
  "char_filter": { 
    "mycharfilter": {
      "type": "mapping",
      "mappings": [ 
        "\\u0091=>\\u0027",
        "\\u0092=>\\u0027",
        "\\u2018=>\\u0027",
        "\\u2019=>\\u0027",
        "\\u201B=>\\u0027"
      ]
    }
  },
  "analyzer": {
    "quotes_analyzer": {
      "tokenizer":     "standard",
      "char_filter": [ "mycharfilter" ] 
    }
   }
  }
 }
}'
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,  I have a bit confusion. How do I push this settings into the elastic server or do i need to do this settings while on search query. i am usinh php curl to push and pull data using bulk and fuzzy_like_this respectively

Comment: You need this setting in your Elasticsearch server not while querying. Eg. curl -XPUT http:// .../your_index -d ' and the snippet above